# Highcharts - Type Bar - single

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am trying to get a barchart to render different color based upon the value (meaning if one line is value 8 i need to get it with everything under 6 is red, 6-7 is green and the rest i green).

For example 
score 8 == [red color up to 5 | blue color from 6 to 7 | green color from 8 to 10] 
score 6 == [red color up to 5 | blue color from 6 to 7 ] 
etc...

I spent too much time on this browsing through the examples on highcharts trying out different jsfiddles... I assume that it is an easy fix but something i have overlooked
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the API-accessible zones solution?
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/plotOptions.series.zones

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts provide color zones API to render different colors based on values.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/izothep/fggr567e/4/)

I have provided a plotOption example as below. Based on your requirement the zones would be

```
plotOptions: {
    column: {
        zones: [
        {
            value: 6, // Values up to 6 and not including will have red color 
            color: 'red' // ... have the color blue.
        },
        {
            value: 8
            color: 'blue'
        },
        {
            color: 'green'
        }
        ]
    }
}
```